# Self as a function in Python?

Tags: python, generative-adversarial-network, pytorch-lightning

I came across this syntax for self(z).cpu and have no idea what that means. I don't even know what to google. Everything I find is "self as a parameter in functions". Not this time. This time self IS the function. What is happening here?

Just to be clear, I am NOT asking what self as a parameter does in function calls. I am asking what self(z) means. why is self being referenced as a function?

```
def plot_imgs(self):
      z = self.validation_z.type_as(self.generator.lin1.weight)
      sample_imgs = self(z).cpu
      print('epoch ', self.current_epoch)
      fig = plt.figure()
      for i in range(len(sample_imgs)):
        plt.subplot(2, 23, i + 1)
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.imshow(sample_imgs.detach()[i,0,:,:], cmap = 'gray_r', interpolation = 'none')
        plt.title('Generated Data')
        plt.xticks([])
        plt.yticks([])
        plt.axis('off')
      plt.show()
```

Comment: Any object can be callable in Python. Look for `__call__`.

Comment: @GinoMempin: `self(z).cpu`